Flutter, Podfile Missing Error, VMWare Pro MacOS , in Webview Project
I using VMware MacOS Montery Public Beta.
I installed flutter and xcode, and install cocoapods.
And ı write this code in main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void Main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement createElement
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'KingsTur',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home: const Kingstur(),
    );
  }
}

class Kingstur extends StatefulWidget {
  const Kingstur({super.key});

  @override
  State<Kingstur> createState() => _KingsturState();
}

class _KingsturState extends State<Kingstur> {
  WebViewController controller = WebViewController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (progress) => {},
          onPageStarted: (url) => {},
          onPageFinished: (url) => {}))
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://www.kingstur.com'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('KİNGS TUR'),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
    );
  }
}


and run this command => flutter run
but giving this error
Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in profile mode...
Error: Podfile missing
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      CocoaPods.processPods (package:flutter_tools/src/macos/cocoapods.dart:169:7)
#2      processPodsIfNeeded (package:flutter_tools/src/macos/cocoapod_utils.dart:43:55)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      buildMacOS (package:flutter_tools/src/macos/build_macos.dart:102:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      MacOSDevice.buildForDevice (package:flutter_tools/src/macos/macos_device.dart:74:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      DesktopDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/desktop_device.dart:119:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      FlutterDevice.runCold (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:533:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      ColdRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_cold.dart:55:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:833:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1394:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:372:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:308:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:130:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#16     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:153:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:93:3)
<asynchronous suspension>

please help me
I want build webview app for ios, on VMWare MacOS Monterey Public Beta
Please help me, how can fix this problem, or write new helpful link, please...
